# Nuxtjs on sub directory

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

Is it possible to have a static generated site of nuxtjs on a sub directory like `feature/detail/*`?

I tried

```js
router: {
  base: "/feature/detail/1234/"
},
build: {
  publicPath: 'assets/',
}
```

but it is working only in `1234` if I transfer the files to other dir, let say `4321` it returns to 404. I need to change `base: "/feature/detail/1234/"` to `"/feature/detail/4321/"` and run `npm run generate` again and upload it to `/feature/detail/4321/` for it to work.

Comment: `Is it possible to have a static generated site of nuxtjs on a sub directory like feature/detail/*?` this is basically asking if we can have **some** parts as SSG while having the rest as SPA? Because Nuxt will generate the whole project in the same way from the root by default. Here, you do want maybe to have a redirect rather no? If somebody comes to `4321`, send him back to `1234`?

Comment: Either way, it is not in the `base` where all the magic will happen. Can you explain a bit better what you're trying to achieve here? Maybe with a [repro] explaining from where your `1234` data is coming from, thanks!

Comment: Im doing an ssg on an existing website and they will upload it to a sub directory `feature/detail/*, so basically the "root" will be the sub directory

Comment: This does not answer the rest of my question. On top of it, what would be the apex (aka index aka `/`) of the website? Is it a Nuxt one? Is it some wordpress or alike?

Comment: @kissu we dont have information about the index of the website also ` If somebody comes to 4321, send him back to 1234?` redirecting is not an option because 4321 and 1234 is an id or slug with other static files .. is it possible if we could just drop ssg to what ever `/feature/detail/<id>` like just dropping a static file to the said directory?

Comment: What do you mean by `Just dropping a static file to the said directory?`? I don't understand what you do want to have there? You could do a wildcard (`feature/detail/*`) but what for? What is the end goal?